# std::thread with tbb - builds with 2 or fewer arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I looked at the fractal example included with threading building blocks (fractal.cpp) and came up with this construct.   Oddly - this works if I only pass 2 arguments in the function.  If I increase it to three parameters this fails to compile.  I suspect it should fail in the original case too - but it doesn't.  Why doesn't it fail with only 2 parameters as well?  Or how do I get it to work with 3 parameters?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <vector>
    #include <tbb/compat/thread>

    void tt(int, int); //, int) ;//fails if 3rd int added

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {

       int numthreads = 4 ;
       int inta = 0 ;
       int intb = 1 ;

       std::vector <std::thread *> mythreads(numthreads) ;

       int ic ;
       for (ic = 0; ic < numthreads-1 ; ++ic)
       {
           mythreads[ic] = new std::thread(tt,ic, inta) ; // , intb ) ;
       }

       tt(ic, inta) ; //, intb) ;

       for (int ic = 0 ; ic < numthreads-1 ; ++ic)
          mythreads[ic]->join() ;

       std::cout << "all done" << std::endl ;
    }
    void tt( int myid, int intb) // , int intc)
    {
       std::cout << "entry " << myid << std::endl ;
    }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the constructor of `std::thread` from TBB only has constructors for 0, 1 and 2 argument functions (see the tbb/compat/thread [header](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506323) ), its not variadic like c++11's `std::thread`